# How to disable Color Management in CoreImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-image, cifilter

I want to disable Color management as described in the best performance Guide by Apple:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html

It says that I have to set null to the `kCIImageColorSpace`.
As `cifilter?.setValue("null", forKey: kCIImageColorSpace)` didn't
get me any results (App Crashed).

I read the documentation:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kciimagecolorspace)

where it says that I have to specify the `NSNull` object as value.
However `cifilter?.setValue(NSNull(), forKey kCIImageColorSpace)` also caused a crash:

> Class is not key value coding compliant for the key CIImageColorSpace

What is the right command to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Amit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the color space when creating the CIContext not to the CIFilter. This is what I'm doing:

```
[CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]}];
```

You should follow the link they posted at then end of the suggestion: 
[Building Your Own Workflow with a Core Image Context](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-SW5)